# Novel about a girl who dreams the deaths of her classmates

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember flicking through a young-adult horror novel, years and years ago, but I can't remember who wrote it, or what the title was. The book was like one of those R. L. Stine "Fear Street" books (Not Goosebumps), or like the kind by Christopher Pike.

From what I remember a teenage girl starts having bizarre nightmares about people being murdered in strange and gruesome ways, only to find that her high school classmates are being found dead exactly the way she dreamed they would die. The first nightmare I remember involved a teen boy being murdered by a hooded cult, stripped naked, a yellow stripe painted down his back and flowers stuffed deep down his throat choking him with pollen. the next day she found out one of her neighbors and classmates was found dead in his room, exactly like she dreamed about, naked, yellow stripe, throat filled with flowers and pollen.

Does anyone know what book this was? It's been bugging me for years!

Comment: Can you let us know how long "years and years ago" may be?

Comment: How did he actually die? Was he allergic to the shocking pollen or did he choke on flowers? Can you remember any of the other death methods?

Comment: Edlothiad: I'm 25 now, I found the book when I was about 12 or 13, but it could have been written from anywhere between the 80's and 90's. It was similar in tone to the Fear Street and Pike stories of the late 20th century. Definitely from before 2000.

Comment: Danny3414: He choked on the pollen, because his mouth and throat were stuffed full of them, he asphyxiated. I don't remember any other deaths, but I do remember, the heroine would dream each one, before it happened.

Comment: This sounds like the story I was writing for the last NaNoWriMo. Obviously that's not the answer, just saying I'd be interested in reading this story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book is [The Dreamstalker](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?14627) by Barbara Steiner as identified by Nu'Daq. Since I have the book I'll add some details.

The protagonist is Karen Newton. The book starts with her dream:

> He can’t breathe. He doubles over and sucks in air, but none reaches his lungs. His wheezing gets louder and louder. Soon he is whistling when he inhales. The boys think that is hilarious. Their laughter surrounds him, echoing through his head, down into his throat, filling his lungs with their squeals and shrieks.
> Their leader, who is dressed in black, eggs them on. They stand in a field of yellow flowers, yellow like the paint that coats his skin, drips onto his toes. He starts picking flowers. Everyone starts picking flowers. And laughing—laughing—laughing.
> They stuff flowers into his mouth. What little air he can draw into his lungs disappears into the flowers. Yellow pollen coats his throat, making it close tighter, tighter, tighter.
> He struggles. They laugh. He falls. They shriek. He lies still. They walk away, pounding each other on the back and bending double with hysterical laughter. It is a good night’s work. A deed well done.

The boy who dies is Gordon Anderson. Karen's friend Alysia tells her:

> “He was lying on his stomach, and there was a huge yellow stripe painted down his back. And that’s not all—get this. His mouth was stuffed full of daffodils. They figure he suffocated.”

It turns out the bad guy is:

> Karen's brother Kerr who has the ability to enter her dreams.

Comment: THANK YOU! That has been bothering me for years! Thank you, John Rennie!

Comment: @JoshuaJamesWilliamSkaug: hi Joshua, note that Nu'Daq answered your question. When I saw their answer I just added some details since I had the book.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like Dreamstalker, a novel I found in high-school. After the girl finds out about each death we hear the thoughts of the one responsible (sorry if I don't give it away), how he thinks the dead person the girl dreamed about had it coming.